# angularjs progressbar value from scope

Tags: angularjs, progress-bar

I have this progress bar value being loaded from scope

```
<progressbar value="{{(sales*1)*100/(stock*1) | number}}" class="progress-xs no-radius no-margin" type="danger"></progressbar>
```

why the progressbar value is not being processed? what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use expression {{}} while setting the value,

Try

```
  <div progressbar="value"  value="(value*1)*100/(stock*1) | number"></div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qnfw80n3/)**